# Как убрать автоматический перенос в выпадающим списке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть выпадающий список, так вот моя идея такова сделать в первой колонке Гиперссылки , а справа от них контакты. Но при добавлении, текста он делает отступ и собственно выглядит это так(картинка и код)
Есть сайт, смотреть только в мобильной версии http://l37-195-222-8.novotelecom.ru/

```html
    <li class="nav-item d-lg-none d-xs-block">
        <a class="nav-link  "style="float:right;"">Контакты</a>
    </li>
      <li class="nav-item active border-right-0">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Главная <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему вот таким простым способом

```html
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="d-lg-none d-xs-block">
          <a class="nav-link  "style="float:right;display:"">Варшавская, 5к2</a>
          </div>
                <a class="nav-link " href="kakproexat.html">Как проехать</a>
      </li>
```